# Visual Basic Windows Shell Launches In 2 Different Directories Depending On User

Tags: excel, vba, command-line

I've had a bug I cannot seem to understand.  I have a very short program in excel that runs a batch file in visual basic.  It is as follows:

```
Dim wsh as WshShell
Set wsh = new WshShell
wsh.CurrentDirectory = "O:\myFolder\myFile"
wsh.run("myfiles\test.bat")
```

When I run it on my computer it works, however, when the user runs it on their computer they get an error:

```
"\\Data02"
CMD.exe was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to the windows directory.
test.bat cannot be found or user does not have permission to access it.
```

This does not happen on my computer and it runs without issue.  I have read some comments that say it may have to do with the file pointing to a network drive (which the user has already mapped).  We are both running the excel file from the same location (a network drive) and the batch file is also on a network drive.  It seems like his command line is automatically converting the absolute path to UNC?  Why the discrepancy?

Comment: It seems permission issue to that network folder that user. Can you check folder permission first?

Comment: Yeah, the user has permission and is able to execute the batch file when run independently of excel.

Comment: Can try `Call Shell("O:\myFolder\myFile\test.bat")` and let us know what happens.

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you.  Unfortunately i'll need to wait until tomorrow to get the user to test it but I will get them to try. I think they have done this one in the past and gotten the same  unc error though.